# Prompt the user for a string in child dialog in a bot

Tags: c#, bots, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am currently playing around with Bots and LUIS.
So I have a running Bot. In my RootDialog, I handle all the intents that I get from LUIS. Now I want to check if an Entity is missing for an intent.

```
 if (result.Entities.Count == 0) {
 var ct = new CancellationToken();
 await context.Forward(new ParameterDialog(), ResumeAfterParameterDialog, message, ct);
```

If there is no Entity I'm creating a new child dialog.

```
public class ParameterDialog : IDialog<object> {
        public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context) {
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }



    public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument) {

        argument = new PromptDialog.PromptString("Please enter a parameter", "please try again", 2);

        var prompt = await argument;

        await context.PostAsync($"Your Parameter is: {prompt}");
        context.Done(prompt);
    }             
}
```

If I could get user input I would then pass it back to my parent dialog.

Now I don't really know how I can stop the Bot and let it wait for user input.
Can someone please explain how I can accomplish that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a `context.Call` of the PromptString dialog you are creating.

The `context.Call` method expects a dialog and a 'callback' method (ResumeAfter) that will be called once the dialog completes (in this case, when PromptString completes).

In your scenario your code should look like:

```
public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument) 
{
   var dialog = new PromptDialog.PromptString("Please enter a parameter", "please try again", 2);

   context.Call(dialog, ResumeAfterPrompt)
}

private Task ResumeAfterPrompt(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
{
    var parameter = await result;
    context.Done(parameter);
}
```